# Probability function that sums to one:

Tags: probability

Given a probability function, how does one determine what a given variable must be for it to sum to one?

So, $p(x) = \lambda x$ for $x = 1,2$ and $p(x) = 1 - 3\lambda$ for $x = 3$. There are no other possible $x$. For what values of $\lambda$ does this sum to 1?

Answer (score 2):

First, the sum of probabilities over all values of $x$ must always be $1$. Therefore:

$$(\lambda \cdot 1) + (\lambda \cdot 2) + (1 - 3 \lambda) = 1$$

Simplifying, the $\lambda$s cancel out and we have $1 = 1$, which is true regardless of the value of $\lambda$.

Second, we must ensure that $0 \le p(x) \le 1$ for all $x$. In other words,

$$
x = 1 : \quad 0 \le \lambda \cdot 1 \le 1 \\
x = 2 : \quad 0 \le \lambda \cdot 2 \le 1 \\
x = 3 : \quad 0 \le 1 - 3\lambda \le 1 \\
$$

Solving this system, the valid range is $0 \le \lambda \le \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Yes, but if $\lambda = 1$, for example, then $p(3) = -2$, which doesn't make any sense.... wouldn't we also want to say that $1-3\lambda \ge 0$ so $1/3 \ge \lambda$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I wasn't thinking when I wrote that. I'll fix it.